Customizing external endpoints Springdoc
I have specified external APIs in application.yml:
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    urls:
      - name: Service1
        url: ${SERVICE1_URL}/v3/api-docs
      - name: Service2
        url: ${SERVICE2_URL}/v3/api-docs
      - name: Service3
        url: ${SERVICE3_URL}/v3/api-docs

I need to add prefixes to the endpoints of these services. I tried to do this through OpenApiCustomizer:
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomizer addPrefixToPaths() {
    return openApi -> {
        Paths paths = openApi.getPaths();
        Paths newPaths = new Paths();
        paths.forEach((path, pathItem) -> {
            String newPath = "/ms" + path;
            newPaths.addPathItem(newPath, pathItem);
        });
        openApi.setPaths(newPaths);
    };
}

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to customize external endpoints from the code somehow?
